# Requests post multipart/form-data

Tags: python, console, python-requests

I want to upload a image but, the code returns https://hizliresim.com. That is to say, it does not upload a file.

The code:

```
import requests
import re
s = requests.Session()
tokenadres = '<input name="_token" type="hidden" value="(.*?)">'
token = re.findall(tokenadres,s.get('https://hizliresim.com/').text)
print token[0]
files={'MAX_FILE_SIZE': (None, 0), 
       '_token': (None, token[0]),
       'local_files[]': ('ss.png', open('C:/ss.png', 'rb'), 'image/png'),
       'remote_file_url': (None, None),
       'upload_setting_description': (None, None),
       'upload_setting_is_public': (None, 1)} 
response = s.post('https://hizliresim.com/p/yukle', data=files)
```

The requests payloads(On the browser):

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryE8nuwMyEFZ25OzGh
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="MAX_FILE_SIZE"

0
------WebKitFormBoundaryE8nuwMyEFZ25OzGh
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="_token"

QV1hXWr4lADl8hFotk3RD8sdvB9LUf8kbAcOuhPo
------WebKitFormBoundaryE8nuwMyEFZ25OzGh
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="local_files[]"; filename="ss11.png"
Content-Type: image/png


------WebKitFormBoundaryE8nuwMyEFZ25OzGh
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="remote_file_url"


------WebKitFormBoundaryE8nuwMyEFZ25OzGh
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="upload_setting_description"


------WebKitFormBoundaryE8nuwMyEFZ25OzGh
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="upload_setting_is_public"

1
------WebKitFormBoundaryE8nuwMyEFZ25OzGh--
```